# From Input to array to mysqli table A, and Update Table B

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, mysqli

I am working on a Stock maintenance project, where I need to show sales, purchases and current stock values of products. The tables I have created are :

1. Users
2. Brands
3. Products
4. Purchases
5. Purchased_products
6. Sales
7. Sold_products

I am working on the purchase form but having problem in submitting the values in the database. the form is like

```
<form class="form-inline" action="#" method="#">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="itemcode">Item code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemcode" id="itemcode">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <label for="Tax">Tax</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tax" id="tax">
        <label for="tamount">Total</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tamount" id="tamount">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="itemcode">Item code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemcode" id="itemcode">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <label for="Tax">Tax</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tax" id="tax">
        <label for="tamount">Total</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tamount" id="tamount">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="itemcode">Item code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemcode" id="itemcode">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <label for="Tax">Tax</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tax" id="tax">
        <label for="tamount">Total</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tamount" id="tamount">
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

and the form goes on for total of 10 rows. What I want is to add an entry in purchase with date and other data in purchases table and if successful then add data of above form into purchased_products table with recent purchase id.

**Purchase table**

- ID
- Date
- client_id
- total_amount

**Purchased_products**
 - ID
 - purchase_id
 - product_id
 - quantity
 - quantity
 - tax
 - tamount

Should I submit the array with lastid and how can I put the array values in insert command?

Comment: Please share your effort to save data to purchases table

Comment: where is your code for sending  records to database